# Menu from mysql db to ul li (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, menu, recursive-query

I have a mysql table (menu) looking like this
id (int)
subid (int)
name (varchar)

subid is 0 if it is top level menu point, and if it is sub, then it get the id from the one above

Data could be

1, 0, Top 1

2, 0, Top 2

3, 0, Top 3

4, 2, Sub 2,1

5, 2, Sub 2,2

6, 5, SubSub 2,2,1

7, 5, SubSub 2,2,2

8, 3, Sub 3,1

I want it to end up with a ul li list like this

```
<ul>
<li>Top 1</li>
<li>Top 2
  <ul>
  <li>Sub 2,1</li>
  <li>Sub 2,2
      <ul>
      <li>SubSub 2,2,1</li>
      <li>SubSub 2,2,2</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>Top 3
  <ul>
  <li>Sub 3,1</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have found a recursive function, but it run a sql query per menupoint, and that can give memory problems on the server.

What will be the smartest way to make my menu?
Should I select all data out in an Array first, or what to do?
And if, how could I do that?

Looking forward to your answers - feel free to ask anything if I havent explained it good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

get all data to array, next make from it 2 dimension array. At the end iterate through all items/keys.

something like this

```
<?php foreach( $array as $ul => $li ) {
 if( $li['subid') != 0 ) {
   foreach($li['child'] as $ul2 => $li2) {
    echo '<li>' . $li2['name'] . '</li>';
   }
 } else {
  echo '<li>' . $li['name'] . '</li>';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to connect for each item, just download the entire table into an array and then sort. The problem I've encountered is sub-menus : how do you distinguish them from top-links? The solution is add a 'parent' and 'hasChild' column to report the appropriate top link and 0 or 1 for hasChild, then call your recursive function with

function would look something like..

```
function myFunc(,$parent,$isSub){
 //database stuff. I use PDO
 while($arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  if($parent===$arr['parent']){
    //make top links
    if($arr['hasSub']===1 && $isSub===1){
      //make subs
      myFunc($arr,$arr['parent'],0)
    }
  }
 }
}
```